# Extjs Buffered store not triggering multiple API/ajax calls

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I have a buffered store that makes an ajax call. I have the API defined to take some start and limit and only return the results between that start and limit. However, I am not seeing multiple API calls being made with different start and limits while scrolling. Instead, I only see one API call made, in this case with start as 0 and limit as 10.  What causes the multiple API calls to be triggered with different start and limit in the buffered store?

My buffered store is as below:

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',

requires: [
    'myStoremodel' // model that the store takes in 
],

storeId: 'myTeststore',

model: 'myStoremodel',

remoteSort: true,
buffered: true,
leadingBufferZone: 2,
trailingBufferZone: 2,
pageSize: 10,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: "/fetch/getNameList" // the API which returns data to load,
    timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'data.name',
        totalProperty: 'data.recordSize'
    },
    simpleSortMode: true
}
});
```

What is the issue here? Any help would be great!

To address one of the comments - the result of ajax call
The payload that gets sent is:

```
_dc: 1647375142598
page: 1
start: 0
limit: 10
```

The ajax call response:

```
{success: true, errorCode: 0, errorMsg: null,…}
data: {recordSize: 10, limit: 9,…}
name: [{id: 1234, name: "Jake_Mar142022", appId: 1, isClosed: null,…},…]
0: {id: 1234, name: "TimMar142022", appId: 1, isClosed: null,…}
1: {id: 1252, name: "RatMar142022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
2: {id: 1253, name: "MycahMar142022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
3: {id: 1238, name: "MeganMar142022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
4: {id: 1191, name: "MikeMar092022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
5: {id: 1271, name: "TomMar142022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
6: {id: 1211, name: "RamMar092022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
7: {id: 1212, name: "JustinMar092022", appId: 1, isClosed: null,…}
8: {id: 1213, name: "AnnieMar092022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
9: {id: 1231, name: "AnnMar142022", appId: null, isClosed: null,…}
limit: 9
recordSize: 10
errorCode: 0
errorMsg: null
success: true
```

Comment: can you post that first ajax call result here?

Comment: @Dinkheller, just edited the post to include the first ajax call response that I get. I have a total of 25 entries but only get the first 10 entries and only 1 ajax call made which returns the first 10 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your total count on the server is 10 and you are sending 10 items.
You have to send the correct `recordSize`, which you defined as `totalProperty`

Comment: I have changed the totalProperty to reflect the total number of entries. However, now I see multiple API calls being made even before I can scroll. Is this because I have set the page size and buffer size to be relatively smaller?

Comment: Please mark my answer as the correct answer. You have multiple calls because extjs tries to grab as many data, as it needs to fill the visible grid PLUS two. If you can see 26 this, would do 4 initial calls. I you want to have less calls you have to increase the `limit` in the proxy. Changing the trailing buffer size does not really do any good, because it effects scrolling smoothness.

Comment: got it, by "limit" you are referring to the "pageSize" correct?